# How to make a regular expression find street/road using Java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to make a regex in Java which could crudely be used to match certain street names. I want to make it so that given the following string:

> Then someone decided to go to the high street for a drink

The term "high street" would be matched. So that is the preceeding word and the word "street" to get the street name. I have tried something like this:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\w+\\s*(road|street|square|rd|st|sq)\\W+)");
```

But this is failing, it seems that Java wants to match the whole sentence, but I am just interested in a few words. I have tried a few reluctant quantifiers as well, but nothing seems to work.

Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `(\w+ (road|street|square|rd|st|sq))` ... doesn't this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you use `Matcher.find` and not `Matcher.matches`.

This works fine on my machine:

```
String s = "Then someone decided to go to the high street for a drink";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+\\s*(road|street|square|rd|st|sq)\\W+)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

System.out.println(m.find());   // prints true
System.out.println(m.group());  // prints "high street"
```

---

You could also simplify the expression a little:

```
\w+\s*(road|street|square|rd|st|sq)\W
```

or

```
\w+\s*(r(oa)?d|st(reet)?|sq(uare)?)\W
```

(gives the same output as above)

Comment: @see: Capturing Groups (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) for more details

Comment: @Ralph, no capturing groups involved really... `m.group()` returns the entire substring matching the expression (even if you have no `(...)`.)

Comment: Mentioning capturing groups is always a useful hint! that's true :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems it was the method I used rather than the regular expression where I was at fault.